# How to get the POST params in revel golang

Tags: post, go, parameters, revel

How can I get the parameters on a POST request in revel?? I have this:

```
func (c App) Ndc() revel.Result {
    fmt.Println(c.Params)
    //more simple code to return a json...
}
```

I have tested many things but nothing works, so I prefer let the code cleaner as possible. This is the output:

```
&{map[Origin:[LHR] Destination:[DME] DepartureDate:[2016-10-31] ArrivalDate:[]] map[] map[] map[] map[Origin:[LHR] Destination:[DME] DepartureDate:[2016-10-31] ArrivalDate:[]] map[] []}
```

The content is good, but... how can I get one by one these variables and their values??
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's all just a simple map and all values are in an slice. To get the `Origin` value from the request:

```golang
c.Params["Origin"][0]
```

**EDIT:** The above does not work, but this should:

```golang
c.Params.Get("Origin")
```

Comment: Thanks @TheHippo but I get this error: The Go code app/controllers/app.go does not compile: invalid operation: c.Controller.Params["Origin"] (type *revel.Params does not support indexing)

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco you are right. There is another way around this. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again @TheHippo Yes... your edited code works... now the question is what way is better (faster, secure...)?? A calling to a function (c.Params.Get("Origin")) or the inspection and indexing of an "object" (c.Request.Form["Origin"][0])...

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco There shouldn't be any significant difference regarding speed. Without checking I would say my version is more secure, because, there will be some checking if a value with that name actually exists, instead of blindly accessing a map and assuming that there is any slice within.

Comment: Ok!! In this case, I'll use yours. Thanks @TheHippo

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the `Content-Type` in your request is set to `application/json` / `text/json`. If so, you will need to explicitly convert it to a map:

```
var j map[string]interface{}
c.Params.BindJSON(&j)
origin := j["Origin"] // etc.
```

Otherwise this should work:

```
origin := c.Params.Form["Origin"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I find an answer, I don't know if it is the best way. After follow step by step [this post](https://revel.github.io/docs/src/params.html), I find the solution:

```
 fmt.Println(c.Request.Form["Origin"][0])
```

The output is LHR.